# how to convert regex code in C# to c++

Tags: c#, c++, c

I have this code in C#:

```
string data = "something ... 1,000 anything 20,000 other thing...";
string pattern = @"[0-9]+([\,|\.][0-9]{1,})*([\.\,][0-9]{1,})?";

MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(data, pattern);

foreach (Match item in collection)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}", item.Value, item.Index, item.Length);
}

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("End!");
Console.ReadKey();
```

... and I tried to convert it in C++ (native code, without .net assemblies), so I get something like this:

```
void main()
    {
        string data = "something ... 1,000 anything 20,000 other thing...";
        regex pattern("([0-9]+([\\,|\\.][0-9]{1,})*([\\.\\,][0-9]{1,})?)");


        const sregex_token_iterator end;

        for (sregex_token_iterator i(data.begin(), data.end(), pattern); i != end; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << i->str() << "-" << i->length() << std::endl;
        }

        cout << endl << "End!";
        fflush(stdin); 
        getchar(); 
    }
```

So, how can I get the index of the match?

Comment: I don't know C#, but in C++ there is not a standard way to use regex, you need to choose a library. Usually the syntax for regex remains the same

Comment: @wiso: [isn't there?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Regular_expressions) ;)

Comment: @wiso Beep... In C++11 there are regexes :-)

Comment: Do you want pure regex-free C++ code, code using C++0x regex support or some code using some other regex library?

Comment: There is even the "older" boost regex library (that was "imported" in C++11)

Comment: @jalf and xanatos: C++ != C++11 and this question is about the first

Comment: Technically C++ IS C++11 and IS C++03 and IS C++<03. The fact that the OP hasn't given informations about the tools he has is HIS problem.

Comment: @wiso: C++11 has been standardized. It is approved and published by ISO, C++11 **is** C++. C++03 is no longer C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this way:

```
struct MatchInfo
{
    string value;
    int index;
    int length;
};

vector<MatchInfo> DoRegex(string data, string pattern)
{
    regex patternRegex(pattern);
    sregex_token_iterator end;
    vector<MatchInfo> result;

    for (sregex_token_iterator i(data.begin(), data.end(), patternRegex); i != end; ++i)
    {
        MatchInfo item;

        item.index = i->first - data.begin();
        item.length = i->length();
        item.value = i->str();

        result.push_back(item);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your compiler, the `<regex>` header might be available, in which case you can simply rewrite the regular expression using the C++ API, which should be trivial.

If that's not available, `<tr1/regex>` might be available, or failing that, you can use teh Boost.Regex third party lib.

Comment: I'm trying to user <tr1/regex>, but, with it, how can I get a "match" collection?

Comment: Have you looked at your compiler's documentation for the header? :)

Comment: @Eduardo - update your question retaining the c# code but explaining you're using tr1/regex, pasting in your code, and explaining what your problem is (compile error? bad results?) for best answers.